# multiple joins SQL query optimization

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have the following query :

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT a0_.id) AS sclr0 
FROM 
  account a0_ 
  INNER JOIN customer c1_ ON (c1_.account = a0_.id) 
  LEFT JOIN sf_user_data s2_ ON (s2_.user_id = a0_.id) 
  LEFT JOIN address a3_ ON (c1_.customer_address = a3_.id) 
WHERE 
  a3_.city IS NOT NULL
```

resulting in the following output :

```
 sclr0  
+--------+
 298279
```

with the following EXPLAIN :

```
 id  select_type    table   partitions  type    possible_keys                                 key                    key_len    ref                               rows    filtered    Extra 
+--+---------------+-------+-----------+-------+--------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+--------------------------------+-------+-----------+-------+
1    SIMPLE         c1_     NULL        ALL     UNIQ_81398E097D3656A4,UNIQ_81398E091193CB3F   NULL                   NULL       NULL                              405508   100.00     NULL
1    SIMPLE         a0_     NULL        eq_ref  PRIMARY                                       PRIMARY                8          evoportail.c1_.account            1        100.00     Using index
1    SIMPLE         s2_     NULL        eq_ref  UNIQ_E904BFD1A76ED395                         UNIQ_E904BFD1A76ED395  8          evoportail.c1_.account            1        100.00     Using index
1    SIMPLE         a3_     NULL        eq_ref  PRIMARY                                       PRIMARY                8          evoportail.c1_.customer_address   1         90.00     Using where
```

approximative number of rows in the tables :

- account : 430000
- customer: 430000
- sf_user_data : 115000
- address : 550000

**Right now, this query is running in 3 seconds. Is there any way to speed it up ?**

the CREATE statements :

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `identifier` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `date_create` datetime default NULL,
  `group` varchar(50) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `sub_group` varchar(50) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL default 'NULL',
  `date_last_action` datetime default NULL,
  `date_last_connection` datetime default NULL,
  `connection_counter` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `connection_since_customer` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `salt` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `roles` longtext collate utf8_bin COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)',
  `is_v3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  `password_token` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `password_token_expired_at` datetime default NULL,
  `is_included_in_newsletters` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `identifier_UNIQUE` (`identifier`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=434243 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `city` varchar(64) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `street` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `complement` varchar(128) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `zipcode` varchar(16) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `cedex` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `abroad` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_D4E6F81F92F3E70` (`country_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=541873 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `account` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(250) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL default 'DECLARATION',
  `last_source` varchar(250) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `source_domain_name` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `subscription_offer` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `formalities_center_address` bigint(20) unsigned default NULL,
  `customer_address` bigint(20) unsigned default NULL,
  `business_address` bigint(20) unsigned default NULL,
  `shipping_address` bigint(20) default NULL,
  `activity` text collate utf8_bin,
  `state` enum('NONE','CREATE','UPDATE','COMPLETE') collate utf8_bin NOT NULL default 'NONE',
  `num_dossier` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `sexe` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `activityset` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `phone` varchar(16) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `business_name` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `payment_method` enum('NONE','CB_OK','CB_KO','CHEQUE_OK','CHEQUE_KO','WAITING','IMPACTPLUS_OK','PRELEV') collate utf8_bin default 'NONE',
  `payment_waiting_comment` text collate utf8_bin,
  `sub_sent_recovery` smallint(6) default '0',
  `transaction_number` varchar(30) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `transaction_date` datetime default NULL,
  `properties` set('ACCRE','CFE','WANT_WEBSITE','HAVE_WEBSITE','NEWSLETTER','SUBSCRIBE','OLD_CUSTOMER') collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `comments` text collate utf8_bin,
  `activity_declaration` varchar(512) collate utf8_bin default NULL COMMENT 'file:///',
  `cfe_center` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `date_create` datetime default NULL,
  `date_complete` datetime default NULL,
  `date_subscribe` datetime default NULL,
  `date_next_payement` datetime default NULL,
  `date_ae_subscribe` datetime default NULL,
  `siret` varchar(128) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `current_quotation` bigint(20) unsigned default NULL,
  `current_invoice` bigint(20) unsigned default NULL,
  `has_create_quotation` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `has_create_invoice` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `created_by` int(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  `updated_by` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `updated_date` datetime default NULL,
  `abo_running` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  `show_bn` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  `taxe_type_activite` enum('NULL','ACHAT','SERVICE','BOTH') collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `taxe_categorie_activite` enum('NULL','COMMERCIALE','ARTISANALE','CIPAV','RSI') collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `taxe_liberatoire` enum('NULL','OUI','NON') collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `taxe_statut_accre` enum('NULL','OUI','NON','DK') collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `know` varchar(50) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `sms_relance` int(11) default NULL,
  `fdae` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `display_fdae` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `show_dispense_immat` enum('RCS','RM','RSAC') collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `show_dispense_immat_city` varchar(255) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `subscription_fdae` date default NULL,
  `nbsocial` varchar(30) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `atclic` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `merassurance` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `dossier_canceled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `dossier_canceled_date` datetime default NULL,
  `tva_intra` varchar(20) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `site_url` varchar(100) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `freeguide` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `hiscox` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `assurland` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `unpaid_advisor` int(11) default NULL,
  `unpaid_date` datetime default NULL,
  `ecl_send` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `ecl_date` datetime default NULL,
  `birthdateyear` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `quaCategorie` varchar(500) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `quaNature` varchar(500) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `quaType` varchar(500) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `april` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `date_guide` datetime default NULL,
  `no_pub` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `campaign_manual` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `export_matmut` date default NULL,
  `formality_date` datetime default NULL,
  `call_count_commerciaux` int(11) default '0',
  `call_count_assistance` int(11) default '0',
  `call_last` datetime default NULL,
  `prospect` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `gender_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `birthdate` date default NULL,
  `current_customer_source_history_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `original_customer_source_history_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `bounce` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_81398E097D3656A4` (`account`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_81398E09E7927C74` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_81398E091193CB3F` (`customer_address`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_81398E09507DD4CC` (`business_address`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_81398E09BA38C653` (`formalities_center_address`),
  KEY `num_dossier` (`num_dossier`),
  KEY `sub_send_recovery` (`sub_sent_recovery`),
  KEY `dossier_canceled` (`dossier_canceled`),
  KEY `freeguide` (`freeguide`),
  KEY `IDX_81398E09708A0E0` (`gender_id`),
  KEY `IDX_81398E0935655550` (`current_customer_source_history_id`),
  KEY `IDX_81398E0981A1F986` (`original_customer_source_history_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=433026 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `sf_user_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `register_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `insurance_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `activity_started_at` date default NULL,
  `accre_request_accepted` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `accre_request_accepted_at` date default NULL,
  `declaration_frequency_months` smallint(6) default NULL,
  `declaration_reminder` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `activities_number` smallint(6) default NULL,
  `computed_main_activity_percent_total` double default NULL,
  `computed_secondary_activity_percent_total` double default NULL,
  `company_address_is_personal_address` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `register_city` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `invoice_last_increment` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `quotation_last_increment` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `asset_last_increment` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `payplug_parameters` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `displayed_first_connection_dialog` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `displayed_first_invoice_display_dialog` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `payplug_parameters_created_at` date default NULL,
  `payplug_first_payment_at` date default NULL,
  `latest_payplug_http_code` int(11) default NULL,
  `register_number` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `register_code` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `register_bis_city` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `register_bis_number` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `registerBis_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `main_activity_type_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `secondary_activity_type_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `declaration_reminder_popup` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `declaration_reminder_popup_latest_choice` smallint(6) default NULL COMMENT '1 = Me le rappeler demain, 2 = Ne plus afficher cette alerte',
  `declaration_reminder_popup_latest_choice_date` date default NULL,
  `main_activity_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `secondary_activity_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `primary_socio_economic_classification_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `secondary_socio_economic_classification_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `income_bracket_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `main_activity_custom` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `secondary_activity_custom` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `default_further_information` longtext collate utf8_unicode_ci,
  `gclid` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `main_activity_type_old_id` smallint(6) default NULL,
  `main_activity_nature_old_id` smallint(6) default NULL,
  `secondary_activity_type_old_id` smallint(6) default NULL,
  `secondary_activity_nature_old_id` smallint(6) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_E904BFD1A76ED395` (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_E904BFD1D1E63CD1` (`insurance_id`),
  KEY `IDX_E904BFD14976CB7E` (`register_id`),
  KEY `IDX_E904BFD1DBC024CC` (`registerBis_id`),
  KEY `IDX_E904BFD12E864BE8` (`main_activity_type_id`),
  KEY `IDX_E904BFD132198C62` (`secondary_activity_type_id`),
  KEY `IDX_E904BFD15543A800` (`main_activity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_E904BFD1798B8812` (`secondary_activity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_E904BFD1D17B29D3` (`primary_socio_economic_classification_id`),
  KEY `IDX_E904BFD17758CEBC` (`secondary_socio_economic_classification_id`),
  KEY `IDX_E904BFD1BAF920D3` (`income_bracket_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=116384 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: In addition to the EXPLAIN, questions of this nature ALWAYS require CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables. It's also incredibly unusual to OUTER JOIN tables from which you select no columns.

Comment: Why you think 3 seconds is slow???

Comment: @Strawberry edited the question with the create statements

Comment: @Rahul without any else around, 3 seconds is already way too much for a sql query in my opinion. but around this query, I have several other queries. in total, the page (heavy SQL page for statistics) loads in 20 seconds. I'm trying to optimize it query by query.

Comment: So, first question: why MyISAM?

Comment: Your WHERE transforms the last JOIN into an INNER one.So essentially you have a bunch of JOINs without a WHERE clause, so an index except those on the JOIN columns is useless here.You can try a loose index scan with GROUP BY but given the number of rows returned even that wont likely help

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this simple amendment will be faster:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a0_.id) sclr0 
  FROM account a0_ 
  JOIN customer c1_ 
    ON c1_.account = a0_.id
  JOIN address a3_ 
    ON c1_.customer_address = a3_.id
```

And if data integrity is important to you, consider switching to InnoDB.

Comment: That's not equivalent. He can (should) get rid of the `left join` to `s2_` altogether, but not replace it with a `join`. Also `city` can be `null`, so the `where` condition has to stay.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Not sure if you saw my edit to my comment. You also have to keep the `where` condition (all cities could be `null` if they wanted to and would count now, but shouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

Change `LEFT JOIN address a3` to plain `JOIN`.  That way, the optimizer could consider starting with `address`.  And add `INDEX(city)` to `address`.

Currently, the `EXPLAIN` is showing hitting 405K rows in each of 3 tables. (1.2M total)  With the above change, the optimizer would start with the city index, there by looking at, say 1K rows.  After that, it would look up 1K rows in each of the other two tables.  (3K total)

`LEFT JOIN sf_user_data s2_ ON (s2_.user_id = a0_.id)` seems to be totally useless; remove it.  (Now down to 2K rows)

Don't blindly use `(255)`, use reasonable numbers.  In doing so, if `identifier` is not very big, make it the `PRIMARY KEY` and get rid of `id`.

It is extremely rare to have 6 different columns each being `UNIQUE`.  I think you will run into business-logic trouble because of it.